# Node script runs fine outside of lambda but not inside

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, sequelize.js

I have a fairly straightforward script that reads summary data from an api and the loops through the records to save the detail to a database.

The code runs without problems when I launch it from VS Code but when I move it into a Lambda function it only runs halfway through.

There are two api calls using axios.  The first gets the summary and the second pulls the detail.

The first call works in Lambda.  The second, which uses the same method, does not.  I can tell through logging statements that the correct data is getting to the second method.  The only real differences are that the second is in a loop and it also uses Bottleneck to prevent overloading a touchy api.

I have put logging statements all over the place but once the routine enters the second api call I get no response at all.  The logging statement directly inside the routine shows that it is getting there but I don't get anything back from axios.  No success or error.

Here is the code.

```
var Bottleneck = require("bottleneck"); 
const axios = require('axios');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

let apiKey = process.env.APIKEY;

var timeDelay = 1000;

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://anapi.com/api/v1/',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'X-Auth-Key': apiKey,
    }
});

const limiter = new Bottleneck({
    maxConcurrent: 1,
    minTime: timeDelay
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    "postgres://postgres:reallystrongpassword@awsrdsdb.cluster-vms39sknjssk1.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/targetdatabase"
);

const notes = sequelize.define(
    "notes",
  {
      appointmentid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
  }, ...
      questions: {
        type: Sequelize.JSONB,
  },
    },
    {
      tableName: "notes",
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

async function notesInject(detailData) {
    log.info("inside notesInject");
    const injector = await notes.create({ 
        appointmentid: detailData.AppointmentId,
        ...
        questions: detailData.Questions,
    }).then(function(){
      log.info("created note ", detailData.Id)
    }).catch(function(error){
      log.info(error)
    })
}

function getDetail(detailId) {
    log.info(detailId)
    try {
        instance.get('notes/' + detailId)
        .then ((resp) => {
                try {
                var detailData = (resp.data)
                } catch {
                    log.info("detailData success", resp.status)
                }
                try {
                    notesInject(detailData) 
                } catch (error) {
                    log.info("notesInject catch", resp.status);
                } 
        })
    } catch (error) {

    log.info("error in the detail instance")
    } 
}

function procDetail(apiData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < apiData.length; i++) {
        const element = apiData[i];
        let detailId = element.Id;
        getDetail(detailId)
    }
}

function getTodayData() {
    
    const pullDate = new Date();
    const dateY = pullDate.getFullYear();
    const dateM = pullDate.getMonth()+1;
    const dateD = pullDate.getDate()-1;
    const apiDate = (dateY+'-'+dateM+'-'+dateD)

    try {
        instance.get('notes/summary?startDate=' + apiDate)
        .then ((resp) => {
                try {
                var apiData = (resp.data)
                } catch {
                    log.info("set apiData", resp.status)
                }
                try {
                    procDetail(apiData)
                } catch (error) {
                    log.info("saveDetail", resp.status);
                } 
        })
    } catch (error) {

        log.info("in the summary instance")
    } 
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  getTodayData();

};
```

I was thinking that the problem was with Bottleneck because that is the most significant difference between the first and second axios calls.  When I isolated the database write code after the api pull, it had the same behavior.  No error or response.

I'm stumped.  I've logged everything I can think of.  Lambda doesn't display console.log messages for this so I've been using Lambda-Log.

I'm sure it's something dumb but it works just fine when I run it from Code.

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Sorry if I posted too much code but I really don't know where the problem is.

Many thanks

Comment: Well, you are regularly calling asynchronous operations without `await`ing them.  That means your loop is going to have lots of operations running in parallel.  It's possible that is causing a resource error.  You don't use `await` when you call `notesInject()` or `getDetail()`.

Comment: keep two things in mind, your coding asynchronous and this can be tricky while working with lambda, however I cannot run your code and check if something's wrong! 
second point: lambda functions have timeout! so if your process takes too much time you need to upgrade timeout in your lambda setting!

Comment: I have await on the constructor in notesInject.  Is that not right?  That was in the axios docs.  This is the first project I've done where managing the async nature of the code was pretty critical.  The lambda function did not appear to be running out of time or memory.  I bumped the cap to see if that allowed something to run that didn't have resources but it didn't change at all.  The code runs in 1300ms and uses 98mb memory.  Well under the 3sec and 128mb default.

Comment: Also, I had getDetail as an async function with await on the call to notesInject but that didn't seem to make any difference.  I've moved stuff around a lot and it wouldn't surprise me if I missed something.

Comment: I've used axios and sequelize in lambda before and it worked.  The only thing I haven't used before is Bottleneck.  When there are 100 objects on the summary page and they all call the api at once I was getting a whole bunch of 400 too many requests errors.  But that was a different script.  I can't seem to get any response now so I can't tell whats wrong.